# Horizontally center aligning a Form Control in form

Tags: winforms, f#

If I have the following code and want to align button control to horizontally center of the Form.

```
let myForm:Form = new Form()
myForm.Text <- "myForm"
myForm.Height <- 500
myForm.Width <- 500  
let button:Button = new Button()
button.Text <- "Click"
myForm.Controls.Add(button)
button.Location <- Point(200, 20) 
// Using this code to align this control to center
```

Please suggest me a good way of horizontally center aligning a control. The above will not work if Form is maximized. And please suggest me to improve the code if there are any other good practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating @ispiro's answer to F# - if you want to recenter every time the form is resized

```
Form1.Resize.Add (fun _ -> button1.Location <- new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - button1.Width / 2, button1.Location.Y))
```

If this is only happending in the constructor, you can just do

```
button.Location <- Point(myForm.Width / 2 - button.Width / 2, button.Location.Y)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I'd do it in C#. Maybe it can help you.

```
Resize += new EventHandler(Form1_Resize);
```

And:

```
void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Location = new Point(this.ClientSize.Width / 2 - button1.Width / 2, button1.Location.Y);
}
```